# Change background color on anchor in listitem when clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I have menu constructed by ul li with anchor tags in each. Css is applied to the anchor
and anchor:hover however I want the selected item to show that it is selected be changing the background a different color. anchor:active does not work.

I am trying javascript but not yet successful. Can this be soley done through css? I have looked at so many examples, but none actually worked right.

JAVASCRIPT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeColor(obj) {
         var li = document.getElementById(obj.id);
         li.style.background = "#bfcbd6";
      }
 </script>
```

HTML

```
 <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
          <li><a onclick="changecolor(this);" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
          <li><a onclick="changecolor(this);" href="View.aspx">View</a></li>
          <li><a onclick="changecolor(this);" href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS - Simplified

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li 
{
  float: left;
}

#navigation a
{
  background-color: #465c71;
}

#navigation a:hover
{
  background-color: #bfcbd6;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to get id again for handling element. obj references the actual element.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeColor(obj) {
         obj.style.backgroundColor = "#bfcbd6";
      }
 </script>
```

**Edit:** And `javaScript is case sensitive`, so you should check your function names.

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/Wjtgx/)

Comment: @acanal Indeed that does does work now, thanks, but it is reverting back to the main color set in the CSS #navigation a. Do you know why?

Comment: If your page changes when you click links, than your page will all change back to default. that's normal. you can't do that with javascript. you should do it on server side. e.g. Home button should be set as active button on Default.aspx.

Comment: See my answer for a javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to use JavaScript to solve this situation. This works for having MasterPage. Changing the id of the selected tab will then reference the css for that
selected tab only while setting the other tabs id's to null.

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="holder">
        <ul id="menulist">
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="#" id="onlink" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="#" id="" >Products</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="#" id="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="#" id="">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="SelectedTab(this);" href="#" id="" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    function SelectedTab(sender) {
        var aElements = sender.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a");     
        var aElementsLength = aElements.length;      
        var index;     
        for (var i = 0; i < aElementsLength; i++)     
        {
            if (aElements[i] == sender) //this condition is never true         
            {
                index = i;
                aElements[i].id="onlink"
            } else {
                aElements[i].id=""
            }   
        } 
    }
```

Css for changing the background color after tab has been selected

```
#holder ul li a#onlink
{
   background: #FFF;
   color: #000;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```